# why doesn't subprocess.Popen(...) always return?

Tags: python, subprocess

I hope this is a simple python question.

When I try the following in the python interpreter:

```
>>> import process
>>> def test(cmd):
...   p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
...
>>> test(['ls', '-l'])
```

It will run the `ls -l`, but I need to hit "return" to get a new >>> prompt.

However, when I try the following:

```
>>> import process
>>> def test(cmd):
...   p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
...   p.wait()
...
>>> test(['ls', '-l'])
```

Then the `ls -l` will be run with a >>> prompt immediately present.

One other variation:

```
>>> import process
>>> def test(cmd):
...   p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
...
>>> test(['ls', '-l'])
```

This will give me an immediate new prompt.

The last example is closest to what I want.  My goal is to launch a child process, wait for it to finish and then use its stdout in my parent process by referring to `p.stdout` while letting stderr just print to wherever it would otherwise.

Right now in my actual application, the last version just hangs at the:
`p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` with or without a `p.wait()`.

Thanks,

Charlie

Answer (score 8):

In the first variation, `test()` returns immediately after starting the process, but before its output is sent to the console.

If you look at the output you *do* get the prompt, immediately before the output of `ls`.

```
>>> test(['ls', '-l'])
>>> total 0                            <----- test() returns, new propmpt
--rw-r--r--    1 foo bar   7 Mar 24 17:38
etc etc
```

In the second variation, `test()` is waiting for the process to terminate before it returns.

In the third version, you're right that you may have to read from the child process's `stdout` for it to continue.

Answer (score 7):

I may have answered my own question.  I believe that in the final case, I need to explicitly read from p.stdout in order for my process to continue.

ie:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.stdout.readlines()
....
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Here is a command that pings Google forever, so it needs to be manually terminated to retrieve the output.

See the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3) for instructions on converting os.popen() method calls to full subprocess.Popen classes.

```
host = "www.google.com"
command = "ping %s -t"%host

#p = os.popen(command) -- using Popen instead of os.popen() to allow calling terminate()
p = Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

time.sleep(5)
print "term"
p.terminate()
pingResultSoFar = p.communicate()[0] # get what has been printed to standard out so far
print pingResultSoFar
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use communicate() method.No need to return.

```
>>> test(['ls', '-l'])
>>> 
>>> def test(cmd):
...    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate()
... 
>>> test(['ls', '-l'])
```

Comment: Without redirecting any of the std handlers of the sub command, `.communicate()` won't do anything useful. It might be better to replace it with a `wait()` call.